# AWS Glue Job Lifecycle - Notebook to Job

Tags: git, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-zeppelin, aws-glue

What is the ideal development lifecycle for glue job development? I've been able to create a run a glue job. The job script window sucks as an IDE, which led me to learn about notebooks. I have the notebook server up and running and I can utilize the same S3 bucket that my glue jobs were using.

If notebooks is the ideal IDE for writing and developing you glue/spark job. Once you have the script the way you want it, is there an easy "path to deployment" to make the notebook a job? I can see two different workflows

1. Copy & Paste - Not elegant but simple, copy the code from the notebook and paste it into a new glue job definition. You cross your fingers that the code in the notebook doesn't get out of sync with the glue job.
2. S3 as the notebook storage - I don't even know if this would work but I saw in the configuration that Zeppelin can save notebooks to S3, is that what you do, is point Zeppelin and Glue Job to the same S3 location

Is there some other way to be doing all of this? I'd also like to utilize Git for versioning of job files so if there's some way to build in that workflow that'd be nice too.

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the notebook into a python script. Here is a [script](https://github.com/sat28/zeppelin_notebook_to_script/blob/master/zeppelin_to_script.py) that I have been using to do so.

And here is the workflow I'm currently using: 
When you merge a branch to master branch, it triggers a Jenkins pipeline that will clone the code in your git repo, parse the notebook to proper python code, build the environment, run some tests and then if all succeed, upload the script to the AWS Glue's script bucket and optionally create a job. Once the job is created, you simply have to overwrite the script in the bucket to update your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up an AWS Code Pipeline that puts code to an specified location in S3:

- Use CodeCommit to commit your local code to a code repository
- Use CodeBuild to take one or more files from the repo and produce an artifact. An exemplary `buildspec.yml` is as follows:

```
artifacts:
    files:
        - "glue_scripts/**/*"
```

- Use CodeDeploy, choose the build artifact as source and select the S3 Bucket as target
- Then in Glue assign the location of the script to the Glue job under "Script path"

Answer (score 1):

I have created a library that packages your code, ships it to glue and orchestrates it by step functions. It's goal is to ease the process going from local development to a run on AWS.

Install it via `pip install datajob`. You need aws cdk installed.

You can find a quickstart and examples in the github repo: https://github.com/vincentclaes/datajob

If you run into issues, raise an issue on github.